# In wordpress to attach different js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In  `WP 4.2` project I attach js files like:

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts', array(&$this, 'admin_load_scripts'));
...
function admin_load_scripts()
{

    wp_register_script('BackendArtistsSongsJs', $this->plugin_url . 'js/backend-scripts.js');
...
```

But I want different pages to attach different `js` files.
I can do it in these ways:

1. In `admin_load_scripts` to parse parse `$_SERVER` and depending
   on current url to attach `js` file I need.
2. In related `php` file
       to include this file I need.

If there is a better way for this and which way do you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a script on a particular page you can use

```
<?php if( is_page('<page-name>')) { ?>
    // You import 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your page and add this script for js file add.
like if you want add js file in `home` page .

```
function admin_load_scripts()
{
   <?php 
     if(is_page('home')) { ?>
       wp_register_script('BackendArtistsSongsJs', $this->plugin_url . 'js/backend-scripts.js');

     }elseif(is_page('second page name')){

     //Add code for second js script file .

     }
```

...